# Remove certain text from php output

Tags: php, mysql, string, preg-replace

This php script basically does a speed test. It works perfectly. The only thing is it echo's the text **MB/s** and and cant seem to remove it from the output. I only want the raw #, like say for example the speed test comes back as **23.76 MB/s** I just want the output to be **23.76**.

Any help would be appreciated. I just spent a crazy amount of time trying to get this and this is what I have come up with. Yes, I looked around the site and Google, but I cant seem to get anything working.

```
//Speedtest Function
function get_speedtest() {
    exec("/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/1mb.test 2>&1",$output);
        end($output);
        $a=prev($output);
        if ($start=strpos($a, '(')) 
        if ($end=strpos(substr($a,$start+1), ')')) {
        $b = substr($a, $start+1, $end);
        echo $b;
        unset ($a, $b);
        } else
echo '0';
}

echo get_speedtest();
```

jj

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I spent a very long time, yes.

Comment: and what is the outcome in terms of code?

Comment: Well, it could be as simple as str_replace('MB/s', '', $output);

Comment: @Fyntasia I tried str_replace('MB/s', '', $output) earlier and cant get it to work. I dont get it?

Comment: Could you post the results of a var_dump($output)?
If it's a string, I can't see a reason why str_replace won't work.

Comment: Check my answer, your code doesn't actually return a value, it just prints it.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this...

```
echo $result=explode(' ',get_speedtest())[0]; //"prints" 23.76
```

Seems like you are running into **`Array Deferencing`** issues.... So do like this..

```
$result=explode(' ',get_speedtest());
echo $result[0]; //"prints" 23.76
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Parse error ? No way ! . Try copying correctly mate. See the second edit.

Comment: Can you `var_dump(get_speedtest());` and update the result in the question. ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `get_speedtest()` doesn't return anything.
2. It's not always MB/s, for example on my connection I got 200 KB/s

---

```
<?php
//Speedtest Function
function get_speedtest() {
    exec("/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://cachefly.cachefly.net/1mb.test 2>&1",$output);
    if(preg_match('/\(([0-9.]+) (..)\/s\)/', $output[count($output) - 2], $m)){
        return array('speed' => $m[1], 'unit' => $m[2]);
    }
    return array();
}

print_r(get_speedtest());
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Can you take a peak at this last question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037414/php-echo-mb-s-speed-test

Answer (score 0):

`$b` is a string, so you can manipulate it to format or cut whatever you want.

One solution would be `echo split(' ', $b)[0]`